# Create multiple independent canvas drawing boards

Tags: javascript, canvas, mouseevent, draw, whiteboard

If I want to create more than one canvas drawing board in a page,
and make then work independently.

The method I tried is below:
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html5-canvas-painting/

And what I did is like adding these:

```
canvas = document.getElementById('imageView');
context = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas2 = document.getElementById('imageView2');
context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');**

tool = new tool_pencil();

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', ev_canvas, false);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ev_canvas, false);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',   ev_canvas, false);
canvas2.addEventListener('mousedown', ev_canvas, false);
canvas2.addEventListener('mousemove', ev_canvas, false);
canvas2.addEventListener('mouseup',   ev_canvas, false);
```

And the drawing is all come to the first canvas.
Could anyone give me a complete code to achieve the goal?

Furthermore, how if I want to store information of each whiteboard?
Like remember all drawing of a whiteboard (not to save it as a .jpg).
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's not encouraged to ask for complete code. Instead you should ask for help on solving a specific problem. See [ask].

Comment: Sorry man, I'm new here. I apology for that..
And thanks for any kind of help here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the function paints on the first canvas no matter what event fired it. You could do this :

```
...
function ev_mousemove (ev) {
 var x, y;
 var context = ev.target.getContext('2d');
...
```

Which should reroute the following functions to the correct canvas.

Comment: Wow, It works!! that's so cool man!
And glad to see any other kind of solutions!
Thank you so much!